# Change previous commit message after merging with another branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-amend

I have a situation where I need the change the commit message of a previous commit on a branch (lets call it BranchA).  I understand that I can change the message using an interactive rebase on that branch `git rebase -i <commit-number>`.

The problem is that I have already merged that branch with another local branch (BranchB).  So issue is that I would need to change the commit message in both BranchA and BranchB. The merge was performed with fast-forwarding disabled (e.g. `git merge --no-ff BranchA`).

Am I correct that git would consider the target commit in these two branches are separate commits? The reason I assume git sees the same commit in BranchA and BranchB as separate is because when I updated the commit message in BranchA, the same commit in BranchB remained unchanged.

Does that mean I simply need to perform the interactive rebase on both branches to change the message on each?  If I do it this way, will it result in issues later in terms of merging, etc.?

Comment: Sounds like they should be the same commit

Comment: They are the same commit, as it is the result of merging one branch with another.  My problem is that, since merging it seems like git treats the same commit it each branch as separate.  I updated the question slightly to better reflect this.